# Problema al guardar multiples registros clonados en laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel

Estoy intentando guardar un formulario con eloquent en la base de datos, en el que pueda añadir varios registros del mismo nombre (ya que son clonados) por el usuario. Para esto estoy utilizando jquery para clonar el div, donde están los campos y los pego en el contenedor, el problema surge que al intentar guardarlos me da un array que no corresponde a los campos a guardar y por lo tanto me da este error: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como front-end html tengo:

```html
<div class="card">  
    <div class="card-body" >
        {!! Form::open(['route' => 'admin.userjun.store']) !!}

          <div class="container_div"  id="dv">  
            <input class="btn btn-primary" id="btn" type="button" value="Agregar">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col"  >
                    <div class="form-group" >
                        {!! Form::label('nombre[]', 'Nombre/Apellidos:') !!}
                        {!! Form::text('nombre[]', null, ['class' => 'form-control','placeholder' => 'Ingrese el titulo de la ubicacion de la junta']) !!}
                    
                        @error('nombre[]')
                            <small class="text-danger">{{$message}}</small>
                        @enderror
                    
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {!! Form::label('Tip_identificacion', 'Tipo de identificacion:') !!}
                        {!! Form::select('Tip_identificacion[]',$documen,null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                    
                        @error('Tip_identificacion[]')
                            <small class="text-danger">{{$message}}</small>
                        @enderror
                    
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {!! Form::label('Num_identificacion', 'Identificacion: ') !!}
                        {!! Form::text('Num_identificacion[]', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Ingrese el numero de identificacion']) !!}
                    
                        @error('Num_identificacion[]')
                            <small class="text-danger">{{$message}}</small>
                        @enderror
                    
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {!! Form::label('Num_contacto', 'Telefono:') !!}
                        {!! Form::text('Num_contacto[]', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Ingrese el numero de telefonico']) !!}
                    
                        @error('Num_contacto[]')
                            <small class="text-danger">{{$message}}</small>
                        @enderror
                    
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {!! Form::label('Niv_educacion', 'Nivel de educacion') !!}
                        {!! Form::select('Niv_educacion[]', $estudio, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                    
                        @error('Niv_educacion[]')
                            <small class="text-danger">{{$message}}</small>
                        @enderror
                    
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {!! Form::label('Correo ', 'Correo:') !!}
                        {!! Form::text('Correo[]', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Ingrese el titulo de la ubicacion de la junta']) !!}
                    
                        @error('Correo[]')
                            <small class="text-danger">{{$message}}</small>
                        @enderror
                    
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {!! Form::label('Cargo', 'Cargo:') !!}
                        {!! Form::text('Cargo[]', 'presidente', ['class' => 'form-control', 'readonly']) !!}
                    
                        @error('Cargo[]')
                            <small class="text-danger">{{$message}}</small>
                        @enderror
                    
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {!! Form::label('junta_id', 'Junta A. Comunal: ') !!}
                        {!! Form::select('junta_id[]',array($junta->id => $junta->Nombre), ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                    
                        @error('junta_id[]')
                            <small class="text-danger">{{$message}}</small>
                        @enderror
                    
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

            {!! Form::submit('Crear directivos', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}

        {!! Form::close() !!}
    </div>
</div>
```

En el controlador:

```html
  public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'nombre'  => 'required',
            'Tip_identificacion' => 'required',
            'Num_identificacion'=>'numeric|required|unique:userjun|digits_between:7,11',
            'Num_contacto'=> 'numeric|required',
            'Niv_educacion' => 'required',
            'Correo' => 'required|email',
            'Cargo'=> 'required',
            'junta_id'=> 'required'
        ]);

       $url = $request->except('_token');
       
       foreach($url as $ur){
            UserJun::create($ur);
        }

        
        return redirect()->route('admin.userjun.create');
    }
```

y como js:

```js
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#btn').click(function() {
            var div_copy = $('#dv').clone(true);
            div_copy.children().val("");//para quitar el valor
            $('.container_div').append(div_copy);
            
            });
        });
</script>
```

El modelo:

```html
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UserJun extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    
    protected $fillable = ['nombre','Tip_identificacion','Num_identificacion','Num_contacto','Niv_educacion','Correo','Cargo','junta_id'];

    //Relacion uno a muchos inversa
    public function juntas(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Junta::class);
    }

}
```

si utilizo dd() para mirar lo que envio, se visualiza:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradeceria mucho sus ayudas.

Comment: Muestranos tu modelo `Userjun`

Comment: ya la edite la pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando haces:

```
$url = $request->except('_token');
```

La variable `$url` tendrá un valor como el que muestras en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces, en el primer loop de este `foreach`:

```
foreach($url as $ur) {
    UserJun::create($ur);
}
```

En la variable `$ur` vas a tener este valor `[0 => "alberto", 1 => "alberto"]`, y eso es lo que le estás pasando al método `create`.

Sin embargo, el método `create` espera un array con las claves que correspondan a los nombres de los atributos del modelo con sus respectivos valores. Por ej:

```
[
    "nombre" => "alberto",
    "num_identificacion" => "343434",
    "num_contacto" => "333333",
    //...
]
```

Por lo tanto, antes de hacer tu `foreach`, tendrías que mapear los datos para que coincidan con lo que espera el método `create`. Por ejemplo:

```
$url = [];
foreach($request->except('_token') as $key => $value) {
    for($i = 0; $i < count($value); ++$i) {
        $url[$i][$key] = $value[$i];
    }
}
```

De esa manera el array se estructurará de esta forma:

```
[
  [
    "nombre" => "alberto",
    "num_identificacion" => "343434",
    "num_contacto" => "333333",
    //...
  ],
  [
    "nombre" => "alberto",
    "num_identificacion" => "343434",
    "num_contacto" => "333333",
    //...
  ],
  //...
]
```

Y ahí sí, puedes hacer tu `foreach` para crear cada registro de tu modelo:

```
foreach($url as $ur) {
    UserJun::create($ur);
}
```